# Return and fill a collection from recursive method the right way

Tags: c#, recursion

I´m about to write a method (or 2 methods) which should RETURN a List of all files in a folder hierarchy (with all subfolders).
I know how to deal with it, when I just fill a global List. This works for me (this is not my problem).
But I want to fill the List inside the Method and therefore I got a problem with the recursion.
So far I´m here:

```
public List<string> GetAllFiles(string path)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();

    FindFiles(files, path);

    return files;
}

private void FindFiles(List<string> files, string path)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                FindFiles(files, folder);
            }

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path).ToArray())
            {
                files.Add(file);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }
}
```

This works works, but I pass the List as a reference, which is not a clean way in my opinion.
How to deal with it "normally"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to pass list as a reference the other way would be to have your recursive method return an `IEnumerable<string>` which is the files for that directory and all subdirectories. This would have the nice advantage that you wouldn't need a separate "GetAllFiles" call.

Comment: I don´t know how to implement this. F.e. where to instance the IEnumerable. Can you rewrite the method above for me?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is pretty clean, because it lets you create your list once, fill it out, and return to the caller, without creating duplicates.

Given the method signature returning `List<string>`, another alternative would be slightly more wasteful, because it would create throw-away lists at each level of the hierarchy:

```
public List<string> GetAllFiles(string path) {
    var res = new List<string>();
    if (Directory.Exists(path)) {
        try {
            foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) {
                res.AddRange(GetAllFiles(folder));
            }
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path)) {
                res.Add(file);
            }
        } catch (Exception) {
            // ignored
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

LINQ makes this even more concise, but the approach remains the same:

```
public List<string> GetAllFiles(string path) {
    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) {
        return new List<string>();
    }
    try {
        return Directory.GetDirectories(path).SelectMany(folder => GetAllFiles(folder))
            .Concat(Directory.GetFiles(path)).ToList();
    } catch (Exception) {
        return new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using yield return to add to your list.

```
public List<string> GetAllFiles(string path)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();

    foreach (string file in FindFiles(path))
    {
        files.Add(file);
    }

    return files;
}

private IEnumerable<string> FindFiles(string path)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                foreach (string file in FindFiles(files, folder))
                {
                    yield return file;
                }
            }

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path).ToArray())
            {
                yield return file;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }
}
```